# Sometimes xcode playground does not work

Tags: swift

I am learning the Array of swift language now but sometimes without any error in the statements, the playground of xcode does not show the result.

Comment: Could you please provide your code that we can  figure out what issue is?

Comment: I am at frist step ... for example I append or remove variable in an array... but sometimes I do not see the result...

Comment: Since there are no return value for append, remove you can't see the result. You will see result for example if you call "capacity". :)

Comment: but sometimes when change the statements It shows the result.... but sometimes it does not show...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've experienced that the playground is still a bit buggy. This happens to me also sometimes. What I will do then is using the `println` method to output or example the values of an array.

Comment: If my answer did you help or solved your proble, please accept my answer by clicking on the 'tick' on the left side o my answer. That way, other people can find the answer easier.